# HTML/JS: Simple "add to cart" functionality?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment for a front-end study programme I'm in, and our assignment says to "update the purchase/cart functionality". I am new to everything JavaScript, and have only been using HTML and CSS for design purposes earlier. My course project is to design, and now program, a web shop for games. I have added an array of games that I have successfully generated into an HTML page, but now I would like to have the "Add" button add the games to the shopping cart. I have tried several different solutions, but with little success.

My product list and my cart are on separate pages, and I'd like to avoid changing that for now. (I might feel confident in adding a drop-down cart or something similar later)

My product list HTML:

```
<main>
    <h1>Game list</h1>
    <div id="game-container"></div>
</main>
<script src="JS/games-cart.js"></script>
```

My cart HTML:

```
<main>
    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
    <div id="shopping-cart">
            <a onClick="emptyCart()">Empty Cart</a>
            <table class="checkout-table" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th width="10%">Price</th>
                        <th width="5%">Amount</th>
                        <th width="15%">Sub Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="cart-tablebody">
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total:</td>
                        <td id="game-count" colspan="2"></td>
                        <td id="grand-total"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="JS/script.js"></script>
```

My JS code so far:

```
let gameContainer = document.querySelector('#game-container');
let cartContainer = document.querySelector('#cart-tablebody');

/* Arrays */

let product = [{
        title: "Assassin's Creed: Valhalla",
        price: "599,-",
        rated: "Rated: PEGI18",
        gameURL: "acv.html"
},
{
        title: "Dragon Age: Origins",
        price: "199,-",
        rated: "Rated: PEGI18",
        gameURL: "dao.html"
},
{
        title: "Resident Evil Village",
        price: "699,-",
        rated: "Rated: PEGI18",
        gameURL: "reviii.html"
}];

console.log(product);

/* Generate Product List */

for (let i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
        gameContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="game-product">' +
                '<a href="games/' + product[i].gameURL + '" class="game-title" alt="' + product[i].title + '">' + product[i].title + '</a><br>' +
                '<p class="pricetag">$<span>' + product[i].price + '</span></p>' +
                '<p>' + product[i].rated + '</p>' +
                '<div class="cart-add">' +
                        '<label for="amount">Amount: </label>' +
                        '<select name="amount" class="game-amount">'+
                        '<option value="1">1</option>' +
                        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
                        '<option value="3">3</option>' +
                        '<option value="4">4</option>' +
                        '<option value="5">5</option>' +
                        '<input type="submit" value="Add" class="cta add-to-cart" onClick="addToCart(this)" />'+
                '</div>'
        '</div>';
};
```

I have tried several different solutions, as mentioned. One of them was the code below, which returned an error of "gameProduct.find is not a function".

```
function addToCart(target) {
    var gameProduct =(target).closest('div.game-product');

    var price = (gameProduct).find('.price span').text();
    var title = (gameProduct).find('.title').text();
    var amount = (gameProduct).find('.game-amount').text();

    var cartitem = {
        title: title,
        price: price,
        amount: amount
    };
    var cartitemJSON = JSON.stringify(cartitem);

    var cartArray = new Array();
    if (sessionStorage.getitem('shopping-cart')) {
        cartArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getitem('shopping-cart'));
    }
    vartArray.push(cartitemJSON);

    var cartJSON = JSON.stringify(cartArray);
    sessionStorage.setitem('shopping-cart', cartJSON);
    showCartTable();
}

function emptyCart() {
    if (sessionStorage.getitem('shopping-cart')) {
        sessionStorage.removeitem('shopping-cart');
        showCartTable();
    }
}

function showCartTable() {
    var cartRowHTML = "";
    var gameCount= 0;
    var grandTotal = 0;

    var price = 0;
    var amount = 0;
    var subTotal = 0;

    if (sessionStorage.getitem('shopping-cart')) {
        var shoppingCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getitem('shopping-cart'));
        gameCount = shoppingCart.length;

        shoppingCart.forEach(function(game) {
            var cartitem = JSON.parse(game);
            price = parseFloat(cartitem.price);
            amount = parseInt(cartitem.amount);
            total = price * amount

            carRowHTML += '<tr>' +
            '<td><img src="products/' + product[i].photo + '" class=cover--smallest" alt="' + product[i].title + 'cover art"></td>' +
            '<td>$' + product[i].title + '</td>' +
            '<td>$' + price.toFixed(2) + '</td>' +
            '<td>$' + amount + '</td>' +
            '<td>$' + subTotal.toFixed(2) + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';

            grandTotal += subTotal;
        });
    }

    $('$cartTableBody').html(cartRowHTML);
    $('#gameCount').text(gameCount);
    $('#totalAmount').text("$" + grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

What am I missing? Or is there a shorter, simpler way to achieve an "add to cart" function?

Comment: Why did you expect that `gameProduct.find` is a function?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I didn't, really, which is why it confuses me that I got that error. Have I written it like a function? As I mentioned, JavaScript is entirely new to me, and I feel like the lessons have been kind of rushed, so I have been looking at different walkthroughs in the hopes that I will learn something new.